# Automated Drupal issue queue workflow

Tags: workflows, community-official-site, queue

Working in the issue queue on any busy project can be quite a bit of work.

Lots of files (patches) to manage, interdiffs, and ideally a branch for piece of work, moving patches forward with rebase etc.

What (if any) automated workflows are there to ease these tasks? This could either be code, such as some form of git wrapper, or perhaps just an explanation of how to use existing tools.

Comment: Are you looking for something broader than [drush_iq](https://drupal.org/project/drush_iq)?

Comment: @Clive I wasn't aware of it at all! I'll take a look, might be just what I need.

Comment: The browser extension Dreditor http://dreditor.org can help with reviewing patches

Comment: Simpler than drush_iq I use an alias to apply patches. http://alias.sh/dpatch

Answer (score 1):

As well as [drush_iq](https://drupal.org/project/drush_iq), you might consider [patch manager](https://drupal.org/project/patch_manager).